# How do I use tr to substitute '--' string

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have an output:

```
--
out1
--
out2
--
out3
```

I want to get the output:

```
out1
out2
out3
```

I thought of using:

```
tr '--' ''
```

but it doesn't recognize '--' to be the first string I want to substitute. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
cat file | sed '/^--/d'
```

Comment: And the 'd' command to sed is pretty non-idiomatic.  Jerry's grep solution is going to be more familiar to most people.

Answer (score 7):

Why not use `grep -v "^--$" yourfile.txt` ?

Answer (score 2):

another way with awk

```
awk '!/^--$/' file
```

Comment: Or, `awk '$0!="--"' file`.

Answer (score 2):

The best you can do with `tr` is delete the hyphens leaving blank lines. The best way to do what you want is [**Amro**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1580845/3960947#1580857) using `sed`. It's important to remember that `tr` deals with lists of characters rather than multi-character strings so there's no point in putting two hyphens in your parameters.

```
$ tr -d "-" < textfile
out1

out2

out3
```

However, in order to have `tr` handle hyphens and additional characters, you have to terminate the options using `--` or put the hyphen after the last character. Let's say you want to get rid of hyphens and letter-o:

```
$ tr -d "-o" < textfile
tr: invalid option -- 'o'
Try ‘tr --help’ for more information.

$ tr -d -- "-o" < textfile
ut1

ut2

ut3

$ tr -d "o-" < textfile
ut1

ut2

ut3
```

It's often a good idea to use the `--` option terminator when the character list is in a variable so bad data doesn't create errors unnecessarily. This is true for commands other than `tr` as well.

```
tr -d -- "$charlist" < "$file"
```

Comment: (1) “put the hyphen after the first character” — no, you must put the hyphen after the ***last*** character of the string argument. (2) The examples you show won’t work — `tr` doesn’t take filename arguments.  You must say ```< textfile```.

Answer (score -1):

You can do the same thing with `grep` as well:

```
cat filename |grep -v "\--"
```

Comment: Useless use of `cat`. (And no, I'm not the downvoter).